# Changing the default plot color of Plotly animated line chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am ploting a plotly animated line chart with below code.

```
fig1 = px.line(df_F_LOW_mode1, x = "Temp(deg)", y=['F_low[Hz]'],
              color = "Device_ID",animation_frame="Supply[V]",title="F_LOW",markers=True)
```

The default output is coming as blue as shown below.I need it to be red.How to approach this.Tried many methods all failed.

I used the this code for updating the color `fig1.update_traces(line_color='#32a852', line_width=1)`

What I observed is that at initial run I am getting the expected color.But when I move the slider the color is changing to it's default value(blue) after that it is not going to the set color.Please see my complete code below.

```
df_F_LOW_mode1['SPEC_MAX'] = 5
fig1 = px.line(df_F_LOW_mode1, x = "Temp(deg)", y=['F_low[Hz]','SPEC_MAX'],
              color = "Device_ID",animation_frame="Supply[V]",title="F_LOW",markers=True)
fig1.add_annotation(x=100, y= 5,
            text="SPEC_MAX",
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=1)
fig1.update_layout(xaxis_title = "Temp(deg)",yaxis_title = "F_low[Hz]")
fig1.update_traces(line_color='#32a852', line_width=1)
fig1.show()
```

Sample dataframe

```
Device_ID   Die_Version Temp(deg)   sup(V)  F_low[Hz]
NOISE_020   0x81        -40         1.6       159.801
NOISE_020   0x81        -30         1.8       162.197
NOISE_020   0x81        -20         2.0       164.386
NOISE_020   0x81        -10         2.5       173.200
NOISE_020   0x81         00         2.7       175.219
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to set the color argument in the `px.line()` call? I don't think `color = "Device_ID"` is a valid color and would guess, that this is way it is falling back to the default.

Comment: color = "Device_ID" means it will plot different color  for each device id.But this color is automatically taken by the code I need to change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- have generated some data to be able to run your code
- as with all **plotly express** figures discrete color sequences are defined by `color_discrete_sequence`.  Have used this, defining *red* as first color
- with this generated data set, the first `Device_ID` is **B** hence it is red and remains red in each of the animated frames
- with animated figures, you have to remember that the traces are in each of the frames (Default frame traces are duplicated in figure).  So if you want to manually update them you need to update the traces in the frames as well as the traces in the figure

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# no sample data, generate some..
r = np.random.RandomState(42)

df_F_LOW_mode1 = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "Temp(deg)": np.linspace(20, 40, 15),
                "F_low[Hz]": np.sin(np.linspace(10 * v, 10 * (v + 1), 15)),
                "Device_ID": np.repeat(r.choice(list("ABCD"), 3, replace=False), 5),
            }
        ).assign(**{"Supply[V]": v})
        for v in range(1, 7)
    ]
)

fig1 = px.line(
    df_F_LOW_mode1,
    x="Temp(deg)",
    y=["F_low[Hz]"],
    color="Device_ID",
    animation_frame="Supply[V]",
    title="F_LOW",
    markers=True,
    color_discrete_sequence=["red"] + px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet
).update_layout(
    xaxis={
        "range": [df_F_LOW_mode1["Temp(deg)"].min(), df_F_LOW_mode1["Temp(deg)"].max()]
    }
)

fig1
```

[image]